# How can I change the address of hyperlink in my application screen dynamically depending on the phone local language

Tags: android, webview, locale

If the phone local  language is  japanese,I want to change  "href" hyperlink to - Japanese:http://jp.example.com.
If the users local language is  Germay,I want to change "href" hyperlink to -  German:http://de.example.com

strings.xml content

```
 <string name="info">
    <![CDATA[
    <P/>Hi,For more information tap <a href="http://example.com">here</a>.
    ]]>
</string>
```

I am loading the contents from strings.xml in android using webview

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
String data = getString(R.string.info);

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(nll,data,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

I want to change in android code before calling webView.loadDataWithBaseURL and not to make change in xml.Based on the phone local language.

Hard coding many url in android class,is not an good idea.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can create different strings.xml based upon the phone's language
Example:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

for more information, you can refer: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

If you want to do it in code, use

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
```

which will return you language code like "en", "es", etc.

Comment: I have already created different values,as you suggested.Suppose I have many languages supported,and to change url need to hard code changing in every values as <a href="http://example.com">depending on language. But can you suggest any method to dynamically assign urls in java code itself.By retrieving Url from some constant file. Before calling " webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(nll,data,"text/html", "utf-8", null)"

Comment: XML is more recommended way of keeping all language related stuff organized but if would like to do it in code then you can use Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() which will return you language code like "en", "es", etc.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply Aaqib.I have tried the solution.I am having more number of languages and that to i have to do it in code and not in xml.Can you please suggest optimize method in code that will be helpful.

Comment: boolean check=data.toLowerCase().contains("http://example.com".toLowerCase());
        if(check){
            String current = Locale.getDefault().toString();
            switch(current){
            case "ja_JP":
                link = "http://jp.example.com";
                break;
            case "ko_KR":
                link = "http://KR.example.com";
                break;
            default:
                link = "http://jp.example.com";
            }
I have the above solution.Is there any other method in code?